# p:dataTable inside c:forEach

Tags: java, primefaces, arraylist, foreach, datatable

I'm trying to do dynamic dataTables. I have an ArrayList with objects of type ArrayList inside, and I want to do several tables with different quantity of elements, but I'm not getting the expected result with this code:

```
<c:forEach var="lista" items="#{controller.listas}" varStatus="status">

    <p:dataTable id="teste#{status.index}" var="obj" value="lista" scrollable="true" 
        selectionMode="single" sortMode="multiple" selection="#{controller.selected}" 
        rowKey="#{obj.id}" scrollHeight="200">

        <p:column headerText="PRAZO">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.att1}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="COMBINAÇÃO">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.att2}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="AÇÃO">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.att3}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</c:forEach>
```

in my controller I have an ArrayList like that:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>> listas = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>>();
```

in listas I have 3 ArrayList, the first with 1 object, the second with 1 object and the third with 2 objects, executing this code it do 3 tables (ok) with 4 lines each (not ok)...

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "_3 tables (ok) with 4 lines each (not ok)_" ?

Comment: You want the 4 objects show in the 3 tables simultaneously?
Namely, each table have 4 records?

Comment: I want 3 tables in this example, but with differents values, the first with 1 element, the second with 1 element and the third with 2 elements, but it do 3 table with all records (4) in each table

Comment: Don't mix JSLT and JSF tags. have you tried `ui:repeat` instead of `c:forEach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @Mindwin mentioned that you should not mix JSLT and JSF tags, I still tried to fix your code and this is what you want:(But I think you should try what @Mindwin said.)

[image]

I didn't edit your code except change `value="lista"` to `value="#{lista}"` .
You should use EL instead of call the lista with simply string.
Good luck and Happy New Year.